# how to convert hh:mm:ss into hhmmss for single data input using shell

Tags: shell

I have time in format hh:mm:ss in a variable and I need to change it in hhmmss format for processing using shell script.
eg.
 time=12:12:10 and I want it in variable new_time in format 121210.
Please suggest command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### bash simply:

```
time=12:12:10

echo ${time//:}
121210
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tr`:

```
t='12:12:10'
echo "$t" | tr -d ':'
121210
```

Comment: Whipe useless pipes!!! You could do same with: `tr -d ':' <<< "$t"` or `t=12:12:10;tr -d : <<<$t`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **sed** command

```
m='12:12:10'
echo "$m"|sed 's/\://g'
```

output will be

```
121210
```

Comment: Under sed, colon don't have to be escaped and while no space, nor special chars are used, quotes are usess too: `m=12:12:10;sed s/://g <<<$m` would suffer.